# How to add transparent grey stripes on forest plot?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm making forest plot with `forestplot` packages in R

With help of this blog(https://www.r-bloggers.com/forest-plot-with-horizontal-bands/), I barely made forest plot. However, in `forestplot` packages, the `hzrl_lines` statement didn't worked as I want.

I want to make transparent grey stripes on my forest plot, overlapping the text. But in `hzrl_lines` statement, it only covers the two rows, not one rows. For example, in following image, I want to cover the 'age', which is category title.

```
hrzl_lines=list("4" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(1:5), col="#99999922"))
```

As you can see, horizontal line covers 'primary analysis' and 'age' category title. The line's center is between primary analysis and age title.

[image]

How to cover the only 'Age' title? I used the code below. I really appreciate your help.

```
library("forestplot")

datafile <- file.path("example.csv")
data <- read.csv(datafile, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
np <- ifelse(!is.na(data$total), data$total, NA)
nc <- ifelse(!is.na(data$intervention), data$intervention, NA)
nu <- ifelse(!is.na(data$control), data$control, NA)


tabletext <- cbind(c("Subgroup","\n",data$category), 
                    c("No. of\nPatients","\n",np), 
                    c("intervention","\n",np), 
                    c("control","\n",nu),
                    c("Interaction\n P Value","\n",data$prob))
tabletext

names(data)
png(file.path("example.png"),width=750, height=750)
forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, 
           mean=c(NA,NA,data$estimate), 
           lower=c(NA,NA,data$lcl), upper=c(NA,NA,data$ucl),
           hrzl_lines=list("3" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#000000"),
                           "4" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(1:5), col="#99999922")),
           xticks=c(-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10),
           clip=c(-40,10),
           col=fpColors(box="black", lines="black", zero = "gray50"))

dev.off()
```

Furthermore, rawdata is like below. It is hard to upload the csv file in stackoverflow.

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(category = c("Primary analysis", "Age", "   60-", 
"   20-40", "   -20", "Sex", "   Female", "   Male", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), total = c(100L, NA, NA, 40L, 60L, 
NA, 40L, 60L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), intervention = c(50L, 
NA, NA, 20L, 30L, NA, 20L, 30L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), control = c(50L, NA, NA, 20L, 30L, NA, 20L, 30L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), estimate = c(-17.5, NA, NA, -12, 
-20, NA, -15, -20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lcl = c(-25L, 
NA, NA, -25L, -30L, NA, -22L, -35L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), ucl = c(-10L, NA, NA, 1L, -10L, NA, -8L, -5L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), prob = c(NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the output of the `dput(data)` command?

Comment: Thanks I put the output of dput(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example URL you provided, the author always had 3 lines covered by the horizontal band. He achieved this by using the middle one and giving it a wide line covering all 3 lines. `hrzl_lines` is there to create a line **under** the current line, so you'll always see the center of it in between lines. The only workaround I was able to find for you, was to add an empty line below your `Age` line and then add the grey transparent band to that line:

```
library("forestplot")

#Create empty df row
emptyRow <- data.frame(X1 = NA, X2 = NA, X3 = NA, X4 = NA, X5 = NA, X6 = NA, X7 = NA, X8 = NA)
names(emptyRow) <- names(data)

#Insert empty row below the 'Age' line
data <- rbind(data[c(1:2),], emptyRow, data[c(3:17),])

np <- ifelse(!is.na(data$total), data$total, NA)
nc <- ifelse(!is.na(data$intervention), data$intervention, NA)
nu <- ifelse(!is.na(data$control), data$control, NA)

tabletext <- cbind(c("Subgroup","\n",data$category), 
                   c("No. of\nPatients","\n",np), 
                   c("intervention","\n",np), 
                   c("control","\n",nu),
                   c("Interaction\n P Value","\n",data$prob))

png(file.path("example.png"),width=750, height=750)
forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, 
           mean=c(NA,NA,data$estimate), 
           lower=c(NA,NA,data$lcl), upper=c(NA,NA,data$ucl),
           hrzl_lines=list("3" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#000000"),
                           "5" = gpar(lwd=50, lineend="butt", columns=c(1:5), col="#99999922")),
           xticks=c(-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10),
           clip=c(-40,10),
           col=fpColors(box="black", lines="black", zero = "gray50"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, your answer was the problem I want to solve. Maybe it needs more complicate ways to move `hzrl_line`...

Comment: I know, I’ve spent quite some time looking for another way but I couldn’t find anything. Adding the empty line was the only way I could find to make it look like only the “Age” line was covered. `hrzl_line` is a bit limited when it comes to that, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found to get grey stripes on one line with `forestplot` is to draw the stripes with `grid.rect()`. A rather time consuming option, but works when you get the coordinates right.